# При клике меняется значение переменной?

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript, html, php

Добрый день, друзья! У меня такая задача! - есть 2 картинки

```
<img src="путь картинки1">
```

и

```
<img src="путь картинки1">
```

и есть в форме скрытое значение

```
<input type="hidden" name="znachenie" value="сюда">
```

и надо что бы при клике на одну из картинок в форму устанавливалось значение либо 1 либо 2. Как такое можно провернуть можно ли вносить в форму переменные JS?

Comment: Переменные вносить нельзя, но можно вносить их значение.

Comment: А как сделать чтобы и value и .innerHTML сработали вместе при клике?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проще простого :

```
<img onclick="document.getElementById('text_field_1').value = 1;" src="путь картинки1">

<img onclick="document.getElementById('text_field_1').value = 2;" src="путь картинки1">

<input type="hidden" id="text_field_1" name="znachenie" value="сюда">
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так можно:

```
<img src="путь картинки1" onclick="img(1)">
<img src="путь картинки2" onclick="img(2)">
<input type="hidden" name="znachenie" value="сюда">
<script>
function img(id)
{
  var name = document.getElementsByName("znachenie");
  alert(id);
  name.value = id;
}

</script>
```